# How can I add to the current value in SQLite column?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update, addition

Im trying to just add on to the current number already in the credits column of the person with their rowid of 0. So if the current value is 5 and user selects the number 2 in a spinner and clicks the button, the value will change to 7. However the value just gets updated to 2. What do I need to add/change to this code to achieve this?

```
    public void upDateUser(int money) 
    {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_CREDITS + " from " + 
                                  DATABASE_TABLE + " where " + KEY_ROWID + " = " + 0;
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        int oldMoney = 0;
        if (c.moveToFirst()) 
        {         
             oldMoney = oldMoney + Integer.parseInt(c.getString(4));
        }
        ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
        cvUpdate.put(KEY_CREDITS, (oldMoney + money));
        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, null, null);
    }
```

Comment: replace `int oldMoney=0; ` with value of KEY_CREDITS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the where clause in the update part

`ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_ROWID + "=?" ,new String[] { "1" });`

I guess it was updated to 2, because without a where clause you update **ALL** entries. It was not updated to 7 because, your Select statement has no results (don't know why, more code would be useful). Check if the select selects a row:

```
public void upDateUser(int money) 
{
    String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_CREDITS + " from " + 
                              DATABASE_TABLE + " where " + KEY_ROWID + " = " + 1;
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    int oldMoney = 0;
    Log.d("com.example.yourapp", c.getCount() + " rows selected");
    if (c.moveToFirst()) 
    {                      
         oldMoney = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREDITS));
    }
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_CREDITS, (oldMoney + money));
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_ROWID + "=?" ,new String[] { "1" });
}
```

Check the log how big your result is.

I hope this helps you.

@Edit: [Documentation of update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)
@Edit2: updated the solution

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It says 0 rows selected. I dont understand why.

Comment: There are two possible options. Either your table is empty (where is the insert statement?) or there is no row with `KEY_ROWID = 0`. Perhaps you can add the rest of your coding. Remove the where clause in your select statement, to know if your table is empty or not.

Comment: I would post the rest of the code but I can only do that 8 hours later due to my reputation. In regards to the insert statement.

Comment: This is the insert statement:       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(KEY_PFNAME, "name"); 
      values.put(KEY_PSNAME, "name");
      values.put(KEY_CARD, 12345678); 
      values.put(KEY_CREDITS, 5);
      values.put(KEY_ADDMONEY, 1);
      db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
  }
This is in the onCreate method

Comment: So I guess the `KEY_ROWID` is an auto increment, isn't it? If this is correct it's starts with `KEY_ROWID = 1` and not with `0`. Check if this solves the problem (replace the both `0` with `1`)

Comment: It is auto increment yes. Now it said "IllegalStateException: Couldnt read row 0, col 4 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized before accessing data from it"

Comment: In which line is the error thrown? Could you add the stack trace?

Comment: 04-14 18:38:08.489: D/com.example.parkangel(8026): 1 rows selected
04-14 18:38:08.489: E/CursorWindow(8026): Failed to read row 0, column 4 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.

Comment: Have you replaced the `4` in `Integer.parseInt(c.getString(4));` ? Use the line `oldMoney = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREDITS));` instead of that

Comment: Oh wow thank you its definitely adding on something, every time I add on "1" it went from the starting value of 5 to 11 to 23 to 47. Not sure what happened to the maths there

Comment: Add another log for your parameter money. I guess your are calling it with different values. Check if this is the error, if please accept the answer ;-).

Comment: Yep managed to fix it, I was just making the method add twice. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

instead of using 
oldMoney + money in cvUpdate.put 
why not create a variable prior to calling put like 
updateValue = oldMoney + money 
and then do cvUpdate.put(KEY_CREDITS, updateValue)

Comment: Will implement this. Also, its not updating because the log say 0 rows selected. Not sure why my code isn't selecting the row with rowid as 0. Becuase I know there is data on that row as I have retrieved it to display on the activity.